# What does "I want you to do me" mean?

Tags: slang, colloquialisms, speech, euphemisms

I read a conversation between two people.

> "I want you to do me on this table."

What is the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: Could you explain the context? What was said *before* and *after* the quote. I'm inclined to think that the two were a couple and one of them is asking for a sexual favour. But maybe because I have a "dirty mind".

Comment: That makes two of us with "dirty minds" then, because I too think it is a request for a sexual favour.

Comment: "You said what???" is the reply. Other person surely amazed with the strange invitation. Thanks Roaring & Mari.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question doesn't provide any context. It is closer to request for proof-reading, which can't be done, either.

Comment: And yet, the post has attracted 9,000 views in over a year, and maybe Roaring Fish's answer satisfied their curiosity too. The OP accepted this answer, it made sense to them. It would have been better if they had added the context, described the scene, but they didn't.

Comment: General reference, no context, attracting
 low-quality answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In that context, it means that the speaker wants sex, on the table.

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dome&defid=518303): *"Meaning, have sex with me."*

In other contexts, it can me 'perform a service' in a more general way, such as asking a hairdresser 'Can you do me next?" in which case 'do me' means 'cut my hair'.

Comment: The phrase (with prurient overtones) has been around since at least 1981, when Carlene Carter included the song "Do Me Lover," a duet with Paul Carrack, on her LP [_Blue Nun_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Nun_(album)).